# Changing the CSS class for submit in jQuery UI

Tags: css, jquery-ui

Hi I am using jQuery UI themes and Accordion plugin. I have two html buttons in Accordion menu. A html submit input will appear when second button is clicked. But submit input looks bigger than two buttons. How can make both button and submit input look same ?

Comment: It could help if you show some code and maybe it would encourage people to answer your question if you accept some answers of your previous questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the jquery UI buttons feature to make it look like the rest of the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Well since you are using javascript anyways you could make the submit input a button instead and submit it with javascript.

```
<form name="abc123" method="POST" action="me.html">
     <input type="button" onclick="document.abc123.submit();"
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with JQuery UI. What I did is changing the font size of the submit button :

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" style="font-size:0.8em;" />
```